# Avoid UI blocking due to lock in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, locking

I have the following problem. I have software which has access to a piece of hardware connected via USB.

In the UI there are some buttons (like search for device etc.)

And you can start a task which will lock the resource (USB device) and performs a time consuming operation on a background thread.

The problem is:
If a button is pressed in the GUI which requires this resource, the whole UI will be blocked until the time consuming background thread has been completed (due to the lock).

I have a few ideas how to resolve this, but all seem to have a lot of drawbacks.

My ideas so far:

- Check with Monitor.TryEnter if the resource can be accessed. ##The drawback is that this requires me to change all ICommand implementations (add the if statement)
- Create another ICommand implementation which has a lock as additional parameter and only executes the method if this lock is free (i would like to have it as a predefined CanExecute statement). ## The problem is, that I am not sure that the change of CanExecute will be populated correctly (i could create a background task which periodically checks if the resource is free, but I think this could lead to racing conditions...)

I am looking for ideas how this can be resolved, if this is not a "constructive question" please feel free to mark it.

regards.

Comment: Add another layer between the USB and the UI? Like, in your viewmodel, instead of accessing the USB directly, you add a property that'll get updated in a callback when the task is done.

Comment: Just use simple boolean flag instead of lock in button click handler

Comment: Why do you have a `lock` on the UI?

Comment: The whole gui will be blocked, not locked ... changed it

Comment: The ICommand has a CanExecute property and a CanExecuteChanged method.  When you start the operation, set CanExecute to false and fire the event.  When the operation completes, set it to true and fire the event.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Execute()`, you can use `Interlocked.CompareExchange()` to set a busy flag before spawning your worker.

Later in your `CanExecute()` simply do a `Interlocked.Read()` to test for "busy-ness".

When your worker completes, simply clear your busy flag by performing another `Interlocked.Exchange()`.

The `Interlocked` class is thread safe; pretty fast; and the above pattern won't block your UI.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an asynchronous lock around your critical section. The .NET Framework provides the `SemaphoreSlim` class that has an asynchronous `WaitAsync` method:

```
System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim _lock = new System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

//Asynchronously wait to enter the semaphore... 
await _lock.WaitAsync();
try
{
    //do your thing in the critical section
}
finally
{
    _lock.Release();
}
```

There is also an `AsyncLock` type which is an async almost equivalent version of the lock keyword available in Stephen Cleary's AsyncEx library that you may use: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock

Using an asynchronous lock you could wait for the lock to be released without blocking the UI thread.